# How to delete the magnification button (lower right)

Tags: notebooks

I'd like to remove that button because there is a white bar on the bottom with nothing on it other than this button. For someone who uses black backround, this is a bit annoying. What can I do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can play with the notebooks [`WindowElements`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/WindowElements) setting. For instance, I have:

```
CurrentValue[EvaluationNotebook[], WindowElements]
```

> {"StatusArea", "MemoryMonitor", "MagnificationPopUp", "HorizontalScrollBar", "VerticalScrollBar", "MenuBar"}

You can get rid of all window elements with:

```
CurrentValue[EvaluationNotebook[], WindowElements] = {};
```

If you want to add them back, you can do:

```
CurrentValue[EvaluationNotebook[], WindowElements] = Inherited;
```